# Already have a Magento website, how to start using Bitbucket

Tags: git, magento, bitbucket, staging

I already have a Magento website, I heard about Bitbucket and it seems to be helpful if I want to start trying working on my staging server.

Do you know I can download the code from the website and add it to a new repository?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new repository by going into bitbucket.org under Repositories->Create repository. Enter all the details and create one.

From the command line terminal go to your project path

```
cd /path/to/my/repo
```

Then fire the below command:

```
git remote add origin https://<youremail>@bitbucket.org/<username>/<new repo name>.git

git push -u origin --all
```

You can also add a `.gitignore` file before pushing the repo.

You can get more information under Repository overview section.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm still facing problems. 
I have my account on Bitbucket, I have my Magento website online. Now I would like to start using Bitbucket, so, in case of problems, I can rollback. How can I link my webiste to my new account in BitBucket?

Answer (score 0):

You create a repository and decide on a branching model that suits your needs (have a look at [git branching models](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branching-Workflows) as well as the official [branching instructions by git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Branching)). Then you commit your existing work to the repository, start working on feature branches and make your web server pull the stable branch whenever needed. As I do not know, what exactly you are needing this is a little vague but still this is the way to go.

Maybe it would also help to have a look into [Google's best practices for modern web development.](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/)